# Looping through rows in a csv file

Tags: python, loops

I have a csv with a column that matches with a Query Set
I want to be able to read the csv, and add the values that match to it for each row.
For example I have

```
('1':'cat', '2':'dog', '3':'bird', '4':'rabbit')
```

and my csv file contains rows as such

```
{'id': '0004B1e', 'first_name': 'Ariana', 'last_name': 'Grande', 'street_address': '211 Sing St', 'suburb': 'Boca Raton', 'state': 'QLD', 'postcode': '4120', 'phone_number': '012346583', 'p_id': '1'}
```

and they match on p_id.
Essentially I would like the csv exactly the same with a new column at the end which for example will say 'cat', for each row.

```
{'id': '0004B1e', 'first_name': 'Ariana', 'last_name': 'Grande', 'street_address': '211 Sing St', 'suburb': 'Boca Raton', 'state': 'QLD', 'postcode': '4120', 'phone_number': '012346583', 'p_id': '1', 'column_name':'cat'}
```

When I try to do it in a loop and create a condition, it loops through the total amount of rows for some reason. (Ie if I have 6 rows, it prints 36 times).
I'm so confused I'm not sure why it's not working

```
pets = list(Pets.objects.filter(Q(mammals=mammals)).distinct().values_list('id', flat=True)
p_id = ids.objects.filter(Q(visible=visible) ).distinct().values_list('p_id', flat=True)
for row in reader:
   if p_id in p_id and p_id !='':
   do something eg print(row)
```

Comment: did you mean `if p_ids in p_id`?

Comment: Why is `pets` a list? It should be a dictionary like you show at the top.

Comment: Because it comes out as a queryset so when I try to add it on, it matches the object as a Query set rather than the actual values

Comment: `('1':'cat', '2':'dog', '3':'bird', '4':'rabbit')` is not valid. `()` is for tuples, but you can only have `key: value` in a dictionary.

Comment: when I printed my csv that's what came out in terminal

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: My example is pretty reproducible

Answer (score 0):

Turn the `pets` result set into a dictionary, then you can index it properly.

```
pets = {'1':'cat', '2':'dog', '3':'bird', '4':'rabbit'}

for row in reader:
    if row['p_id'] in pets:
        row['column_name'] = pets[row['p_id']]
    # do something with row
```

Use `csv.DictReader` so that the rows will be dictionaries rather than lists, so you can use named keys.

Comment: Hmmm it still prints rows more than once. I can't figure out why

Comment: What happens if you just do `for row in reader: print(row)`?